# maven failsafe -Dtest reports written to surefire=reports folder

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I work on a multi module project. We have UT and IT in each module. 
We use failsafe plugin to execute integration tests. 
We need to be able to execute a single integration test from command line (it works fine in eclipse).
When i issue 
`mvn verify -rf cmil-document -Dtest=IDocumentFacadeIT#changeDocumentTest`
the test is executed - I see output log in system console. 
At first I wasn't able to find the failsafe report. Later I checked surefire reports folder and I found the integration test report in it.

Well it is not a big deal to open it from the displaced location, but still my question is:
Do I miss the proper way to run a single integration test or maven/one of the plugins is somehow consfused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Dtest` is for surefire, whereas for failsafe you should use `-Dit.test`, see the User Property for [test](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#test)

Comment: Robert, thanks for the correct answer! Actually I started liking the idea to be able to send IT reports to surefire folder. The use case is: run all IT and keep them for reference in the failsafe reports folder. Then run the failed tests one by one with -Dtest instead of -Dit.test, so the individual reports go to surefire folder. this way I'm able to check upon changes while fixing the failed tests/app.